# jQuery click function problem

Tags: jquery, click, appendto

I am having a bit of trouble on how to apply jquery event helpers on selectors that have been appendTo.
I have this code:

```
$('<input/>').attr({ id: 'submitbtn', type: 'submit', value: 'Click me' }).appendTo('form');
```

Now, when I try to use click function on this appended submit button nothing happens

```
$('input#submitbtn').click(function() { // code here });
```

While it works fine if this element was pure html. How can I make this work? Any help appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/jackJoe/b84RB/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use live events:

```
$('input#submitbtn').live('click', function(e) {
    /* code here */
})
```

Regular events are only bound to elements which exist at the time where the event is bound.

PS: I hope you only create **one** button. IDs **must be unique** - things will usually break if they aren't. If you plan to create multiple buttons, use classes instead of IDs and `.` instead of `#` in the selector.

Comment: @jackJoe: not if he creates the button after binding the handler;
@user558134: i'd suggest you to choose a nickname instead of the default one

Comment: ok, good point, I didn't realise the OP would append it afterwords.